# Changing dynamically-generated input size without touching CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this html line for an input field, generated dynamically by js code, which should be limited to 4 characters (in this case I prefer to use as unit the characters and not the pixels, by the way)

`<input id="40" type="number" maxlength="4" size="4" value="0">`

But the width of the input field is way more than the desired 4 characters.

Checking the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/size) I discovered what is likely the problem:

> *If CSS targets the element with properties impacting the width, CSS takes precedence.*

My problem now is that I'm using a third party CSS file -full of *fill-available* here and there- and I absolutely don't want to mess with it, because overall the layout is very nice (which is a thing I usually can't manage to obtain when I start to write CSS on my own).

So my question is: there is a html/js way to tell to the browser that, in this specific case, it must ignore the CSS regarding the size of the input field?

Comment: What does `width: unset` do?

Comment: @isherwood apparently not much, at least if I insert it directly in the element like style="width:unset", at least in last chromium version. I suppose that a way to use it it is to create a class in css. But now that you made me think of it, I can as well use style="width:6em" (+50% to take in account font differences), it won't be pixel exact, but reading again the "size" documentation, neither "size" is pixel exact. Thanks. :)